# How to access embbeded cordova webview in plugin?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins

I made a controller that inherit embedded cordova webview.
And I created a custom plugin.

javascript call custom plugin method.

I want to access my controller that inherit embedded cordova webview in plugin method.

```
// MyPlugin.m
@import "MyPlugin.h"
@import "MyController.h"

@implementation myPlugin
- (void) myPluginMethod: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
    // How to access my controller that inherit embedded cordova webview in this.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a regular plugin you can get the viewController with

```
self.viewController
```

But, as you are using an embedded cordova webview it might not work.

So, if it doesn't work you can always get the rootViewController like this:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
```

If you want to access the webView just use

```
self.webView
```

Comment: I don't want to access the webView. I want to access MyController or CDVViewController.